# How can I give PHP access to a COM object?

Tags: php, com

I am running PHP 5.3 on my local Windows 7 Laptop (have tried this all on our development server with no success, so I tried to see if I could get it to work on my laptop successfully first). When I call the following script:

```
$objAltovaXML = new COM('AltovaXML.Application');
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `AltovaXML.Application': Access is denied.

I have checked using a PowerShell script I have found elsewhere on StackOverflow and have confirmed tht AltovaXML.Application is properly registered.

But how do I give my PHP script access to it?

Comment: Did you try opening other applications using PHP. I tried on my CLI and word is opening perfectly. Try the following code
`<?php
 $word=new COM("word.application") or die("Cannot start word for you"); 
 print "Loaded word version ($word->Version)\n"; 
 $word->visible =1; 
 $word->Documents->Add(); 
 $word->Selection->Typetext("Hello World PHP Testing"); 
 $word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("test doc.doc"); 
 $word->Quit(); 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

While it should work I would just wrap a script around COM object and invoke that script via [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Saves you a lot of trouble and is easy to debug separately and understand what exactly is going on.